# How to bind keyboard delete key using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I have a relaycommand in viewmodel.

```
 DeleteCommand = new RelayCommand<Customer>(param =>
  {
 //my code
  });
```

I bind this command to a button, and  i want to bind this to delete key.

```
<KeyBinding  Key="Delete"
        Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=CustomerListView}"/>
```

It is work on button, but dont work on delete key.

```
<DataGrid Margin="10" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CellStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridCell}" Height="310" Name="CustomerListView"  filter:DataGridExtensions.UseBackgroundWorkerForFiltering="True"
    filter:DataGridExtensions.IsClearButtonVisible="False" IsReadOnly="True"
   filter:DataGridExtensions.IsFilterVisible="True"
   ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey 
    TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type filter:DataGridHeaderFilterControl}, 
    ResourceId=DataGridHeaderFilterControlStyle}}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CustomerCollection}" >
     <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn  Width="100" Header="Code" Binding="{Binding Path=Code}"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="200"/>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
    <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding EditCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=CustomerListView}" />
   </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Where do you define the KeyBinding and where's the focus when you press the key?

Comment: I add in `<Window.InputBindings>`, and focus is in listviewitem. it work for `<KeyBinding Modifiers="Control"  Key="E"`

Comment: Post your code including the ListView: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: plz see my edit

Comment: So now you have a DataGrid but no ListView...?

Comment: I have a button that use this command, and work. `<Button Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=CustomerListView}"  ToolTip="حذف" ToolBar.OverflowMode="AsNeeded" />`

Comment: How is this related to your issue? Which element is focused when you press the key?

Comment: DataGridItem is focus, it work for `<KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="E"`

Comment: Add the KeyBinding to  <DataGrid.InputBindings>?

Answer (score 4):

Easy as a pie:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

For more information please look [HERE](https://programmingistheway.wordpress.com/2015/07/08/wpf-mvvm-binding-command-to-key-press/)

Comment: where and how  are you binding your View to ViewModel?

Comment: the approach also works with `DataGrid.InputBindings` in case you have multiple grid in a window